# Match multiple Partial Text in one cell & return Max date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to match partial data from multiple cells and want Max date in return. Tried Max index match and search function but no luck. If anyone can help.

Example:

Sheet1-
**Column A:**
**Row1-** ahah_ah-ata_KH_079 to ahjhd_Baker
**Row2-** ahah_ah-ata_KH_079 to ahjhd_Baker

**Column B:**
**Row1-**12/5/2020  11:58:00 PM
**Row1-**12/5/2020  11:31:00 PM

**Sheet:2
Column A:**
**Row1-** KH_0278
**Row2-** KH_079
**Row3-** DUA001

**Column B:**
**Row1-** KH_0275
**Row2-** Baker
**Row3-** BBA001

**Expected Return:**
In
**Sheet:2- Column C:**
**Row1-** NA
**Row2-** 12/5/2020  11:58:00 PM
**Row3-** NA

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(MAXIFS(Blad1!B$1:B$2,Blad1!A$1:A$2,"*"&A1&"*",Blad1!A$1:A$2,"*"&B1&"*")=0,"NA",MAXIFS(Blad1!B$1:B$2,Blad1!A$1:A$2,"*"&A1&"*",Blad1!A$1:A$2,"*"&B1&"*"))`

Use this formula in Sheet2 cell `C1`.
It checks the partial match of both `A1` & `B1` in the given range in Sheet1 column A and returns the maximum value of Sheet1 column B from the matching range of column A.

Since this formula returns `0` if there's no match I added the IF statement.